# PEX - Do not install tubing above or below septic tanks, leach fields, pits, or cesspools - why?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am reading the "Installation Manual for Viega PureFlow Water System" and on page 41 it states:

> Do not install Viega PureFlow PEX tubing where soil is or may become contaminated with solvents, fuels or similar chemicals.

AND

> Do not install tubing above or below septic tanks, leach fields, pits, or cesspools.

Why?

Source:
https://www.viega.us/content/dam/viega/aem_online_assets/download_assets/us/impf_724596_0820_pureflow_water_system.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Basic cross-contamination protection. Same basic idea of not putting the latrine upstream of the drinking water intake, or more pithy sayings I can't say here as they refer to human food byproducts by pithy rude names.

Comment: So this is simply a common practice regardless of the piping. For some reason, I thought it was because PEX is permeable and would allow undesirable material permeate though the PEX material and contaminate the clean supply of water.